# How can I add items locally to my Visual Studio solution and not have git save them?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm working with 3 other developers on a large project, this project is under source control through git. A lot of what I do is database related, so I originally created a separate solution in Visual Studio for all my DB work (I don't like to use SSMS).

For what I'm currently doing It could be useful to add my database solution to the actual project solution so I can work on them simultaneously.

The problem is... if I do that, next time I do a commit my database project will also be committed, which is not exactly my intention. Most of what is in there are trials, several versions of stored procs and triggers... nothing that my colleagues really have any use for.

Is there a way I can add it to the solution without unintentionally polluting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your DB solution in .gitignore file

Comment: And how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to ignore a whole project you want to add it to your .gitignore file.
If there is not .gitignore in your project create one at the root level of your git repository.
The following line ignores a directory:

```
project_you_want_to_ignore/
```

Note that this only works, if the directory is not under git version control right now. If it is you have to remove it first.

You can find more info on the topic [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)